# How can I store a dynamic text value in selenium ide and use it later in different window

Tags: selenium

I am new in selenium and trying to learning. I am creating a script and I got stuck here, I want to store a dynamic value from text message on web page ex. " Event Name:Test" this Event Name is dynamic and I want to store this and want to get in other window. In 2nd window i want to use this value(Test) to verify in the page
I tried storeValue, StoreText and storeAttribute command and getting error message for xpath or "element not found".
Please help me and advice me , what should I do?
Can You please suggest me the Xpath for storing and retrieving the event name. Please help me...

Thanks in advance,
Niru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the same test-case to navigate from **page 1** to **page 2** you can use the `storeText` function in the IDE to store the value of your event name. And then you can use the same variable in the **page 2** for verification.

For example, in **page 1** to store the value of event you use:

```
storeText(locator1, temp)
```

And then on **page 2** you use assert:

```
assertText(locator2, ${temp})
```